# Ports required for web login with domain SSO

Tags: active-directory, iis, kerberos

I have a IIS on a server which is a member of an AD domain. The app is using Windows Integrated Authentication and users want single sign-on.  Besides the web app's port (80) are there additional ports required:

- Between the client PC and the web server?
- Between the web server and the domain controllers?

I am asking this because the customer is putting the web server behind a firewall and will open specific ports upon request only.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't. Client authentication data is sent in the standard HTTP `Authorization:` header. Kerberos tokens are validated by the server itself (against its keytab or 'machine password'), and using the regular AD login protocol  for NTLM.